# Querying a many to many join table with HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I need some advice for creating a hql query.

Situation: I have set of `Nodes` to which can be assigned a configurable amount of `Flags`. To do this I have the following classes/tables:

Classes:

```
class Node {
  String name
}

class Flag {
  String name
}

class NodeHasFlag {
  Node node
  Flag flag
  boolean value
}
```

Resulting tables with some sample data:

```
Node
id, name
1,  'a'
2,  'b'
3,  'c'
...

Flag
id, name
1,  'visible'
2,  'special'
...

NodeHasFlag
node_id, flag_id, value
1,       1,       true      // node 'a' is visible
2,       1,       false     // node 'b' is not visible
2,       2,       true      // node 'b' is special
3,       1,       false     // node 'c' is not visible
...
```

Now I need a hql query to get a list of nodes based on flags.

Like: Give me all nodes that are `visible` and `special`

Or: Give me all nodes that are `visible` and have an undefined value for `special` (no entry in `NodeHasFlag` table)

Checking for a single flag is easy but checking for multiple flags at same time is causing me trouble.

I'am using Grails and Gorm but I think the problem would be the same with standard Java Hibernate

Comment: The problem is HQL doesn't support intersects or unions. You could do each HQL statement and then intersect the lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can solve this with subqueries. The first example might look like this. The second example would need LEFT JOIN and an OR IS NULL restriction.

```
    select n from Node n
        where n.id in 
            (select n2.id from Node n2 
                join n2.flags f2 
                where f2.visible = :visibleValue)
       and n.id in
            (select n3.id from Node n3
                join n3.flags f3
                where f3.special = :specialValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also get creative (assuming NodeHasFlag never has the same node_id and flag_id) and try something like this:

```
// Both visible and special
select n from Node n
   where 3 = (
     select SUM(CASE f.name WHEN 'visible' THEN 2 WHEN 'special' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      from n.flags f))
```

or

```
// Visible but not special
select n from Node n
   where 2 = (
    select SUM(CASE f.name WHEN 'visible' THEN 2 WHEN 'special' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      from n.flags f))
```

A little more optimized but less intuitive :)

Comment: Thanks for this idea but I think carbontax's approuch is more reliable.

Comment: @Jim Sosa - I personally have a weakness for such creative approaches, but they rarely survive the situations real life will throw at your application. Still, it is tempting. :)